# F#: Lookup on object of indeterminate type When using FluntNHibernate

Tags: function, fluent-nhibernate, f#

I try to configure NHibernate in F# project by FluentNHibernate.

```
 static member GetNHibernateConfig = 
    Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                .ConnectionString(fun c -> c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("connectionString") |> ignore)
                    .ShowSql())
```

Visual Studio highlight "c.FromConnectionStringWithKey" with error:

Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know anything about this, but from searching the web for API docs, I would try
 changing

```
fun c ->
```

to

```
fun (c:ConnectionStringBuilder) ->
```

because this

http://fluentnhibernate.org/api/FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db/PersistenceConfiguration%602.htm#ConnectionString

suggests to me that that may be the type of `c`.

EDIT:

(Apparently the type is `MsSqlConnectionStringBuilder`.)

Anyway, more generally, if you run into F# not inferring lambda types when C# does, then probably

- you're using a method with multiple overloads
- some subset of the overloads use `Action` or `Func`

and the easiest thing is to explicitly add the `Action` or `Func` delegate type so that F# correctly resolves the overload.  In this case, I think changing

```
.ConnectionString(fun c -> ...)
```

to

```
.ConnectionString(Action<MsSqlConnectionStringBuilder>(fun c -> ...))
```

fixes it, and this is often the most expedient way to get unblocked.

Comment: It's not compatible with any overload, it says `ConnectionStringBuilder -> unit` is not compatible with `MsSqlConnectionStringBuilder -> unit`, and `ConnectionStringBuilder -> unit` not compatible with `string`

Comment: Then type it adding the `MsSql` prefix.  Then I expect it will work.

Comment: Also, I expect that wrapping `new Action<_>(...)` around the `fun c ->` lambda will work.

Comment: It only works when explicitly stating the Action type parameter, e.g. `Action<MsSqlConnectionStringBuilder>`

Comment: y saved my day Brian :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but declaring the type of the function parameter works:

```
Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
            .ConnectionString(fun (c: MsSqlConnectionStringBuilder) -> c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("connectionString") |> ignore)
                .ShowSql())
```

Anyway, you'll be better off using [FunctionalNHibernate](https://www.ohloh.net/p/FunNH) instead of FluentNHibernate in F#.

Comment: As to why, presumably there are multiple overloads of `.ConnectionString`, and C# and F# type inference work differently and I guess C# figures it out but F# does not.

Comment: @Brian: weird thing is, one overload takes an `Action<_>` and the other one takes a string. There should be no confusion?

Comment: More precisely, an `Action<MsSqlConnectionStringBuilder>`

Comment: F# type inference does not work that way.  If there are two overloads, one taking an `Action` and the other a string, and you pass a lambda, F# does not resolve to the `Action` one before typechecking the lambda.  C# does.  I expect you can also fix this by explicitly adding `new Action<_>(fun c ->`.